# brokenpenalty for two sided documents

Tags: hyphenation, double-sided

A hyphenated word where one part is on the left and the other part on the right page of a doubled sided document isn't so bad and sometimes necessary to prevent ugly page breaks.

However, I would like to prevent hyphenated words where one part is on the right and the other on the left page (so that the reader needs to turn the page over to read the complete word). So I'm looking for a brokenpenalty which can do this.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/french-typography-recommendations

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your response. Did the find a solution for my problem? I only see the standard solution with brokenpenalty, which affects both recto and verso pages.

Comment: Not sure about this. But I don't see much difference between odd and even pages: if you want to avoid the last line being hyphenated, this should be independent of the side.

Comment: This is a good  question but really there is no good solution in TeX, the line breaking and page breaking happen at different times.

Comment: @egreg The intention behind this is that I find a word break where you have to turn the page more annoying than when you just have to slightly adjust your view on to the top of the next page. As the hyphenated words help to avoid undefull vboxes it is a trade-off decision which I would like to answer with preventing only some of the hyphenations.

Comment: @user2653422 you can manually surround words with `\mbox` to avoid bad hyphenation points but there is no fully robust way to automate this in tex. The page is not known at the point linebreaking decisions are made.

Comment: The issues are the same as for controlling hyphenation around floats: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179515/general-question-about-controlling-hyphenation-and-document-layout/179519#179519

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, good explanation. As there are not so many hyphenated words over page breaks I think the `\mbox` will do the trick.